# Segue to new view controller

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, segue

So I implemented an FB login into my app with the following in view controller.swift file

```
func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {

    if error == nil
    {
        print("Login Successful")
    }
    else
    {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```

From this point though I am not sure how/where to call a function to segue after a successful login, I am new to swift so any detailed explanation would be great.

Comment: Easiest way, add a segue in storyboard, assign an identifier, and call `performSegueWithIdentifier`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is fine , at the same time you need to implement the `performSegueWithIdentifier` for segue

[image]

```
use segue identifier in Push Method and give the proper connection
```

if you are using `Identifier`, then call this line where u need
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("identifierName", sender: self)

```
  func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {

    if error == nil
    {
        print("Login Successful")
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("identifierName", sender: self)
    }
    else
    {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```

**Choice-2**

```
if use `storyboard ID` with connection less
```

for example

[image: I have given segue identifier in SeconViewController as in the image.]

```
func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {

    if error == nil
    {
        print("Login Successful")
          let second = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewControllerSegue") as? SecondViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(second!, animated: true)
    }
    else
    {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a segue between your view controllers in storyboard set the identifier in attributes inspector for example "showNexController" and do that :

```
func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
   if (error) { 
     print("Process error")
   } else if (result.isCancelled) {
     print("Cancelled")
   } else {
     print("Logged in")
     // Perform segue here
     performSegueWithIdentifier("showNexController", sender: self)
   }
}
```

Comment: so keep it within the same function right? Don't create a new function?

Comment: you need to trigger the segue when the login is successful, therefore you just need to call performSegueWithIdentifier within this closure You can create a seperate function that has performSegueWithIdentifier plus any other logic you want to add but you're still going to need to call it within this closure.

Comment: If you want to do more actions in the logged in case before perform segue you can declare your function otherwise don't.